# Swift NSURLCONNECTION fatal error while parsing json

Tags: xcode, swift

I am trying to access an api using the following code. 
I am getting the error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when I am trying to parse json.

I am not sure why is that error happening.
The data is not nil.

```
var urlFull = NSURL(string: url)!
    var urlrequest = NSURLRequest(URL: urlFull)
    let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlrequest, queue: queue, completionHandler: {
        (response, data, error) -> Void in
        println(response)
        println(data)
        println(error)

        if let anError = error {
            println(error)
        } else {
            var jsonError: NSError? = nil
            let post = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as NSDictionary
            if let aJSONError = jsonError {
                println("Error parsing")
            } else {
                println("The post is: " + post.description)
            }


        }
    })
```

Comment: Could you please mark the line of code where you get the error. Thanks

Comment: on line let post = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as NSDictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your forced cast: `as NSDictionary`. Whatever's being returned can't be casted to `NSDictionary`.

You should always use optional casting (`as?`) and optional unwrapping (`if let…`) when parsing JSON:

```
let post = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as? NSDictionary

if let post = post {
    // it worked! parse post
} else {
    // it's not a dictionary.
    println(post)
    // see what you have and debug from there
}
```